# Validation not working when adding query string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

My validations are not working when redirecting from **one page to another on passing query string as a parameter** with `response.redirect` or with `windows.location.href`.

When I am redirecting from one page to another page with this:

```
<asp:Button ID="New" runat="server" Text="New" OnClientClick="Transfer()" />

 function Transfer() {
        window.location.href = "Abc.aspx?flag=yes"; //when adding query string my validation doesnt work
        //window.location.href = "Abc.aspx";// When removing query string my validation successfully works
    }
```

Then I have tried from server side like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="New" runat="server" Text="New" OnClick="New_Click" />
 protected void btnNewApplicant_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Abc.aspx?flag=yes", false); //again not working with this.
        }
```

When I click on this **New** button i am getting error in console:

[image]

Is this error has to do anything with this option: `EnableEventValidation="false"` as you can see in my code?

**Note**: I need to pass parameter as query string for some reason.

**Abc.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Theme="---" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="---" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="---" EnableEventValidation="false" Inherits="---" %>

     <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rf1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="require" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txt1" Display="None" ValidationGroup="validate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

     <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rf2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="require" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txt2" Display="None" ValidationGroup="validate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="validate" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="true" OnClientClick="checkvalidation()"/> //on click of this i want to perform validation but it is not working.
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="radcodeblock1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkvalidation() {
            window.Page_ClientValidate('validate');
            var counter= 0;
            var val= '';
            for (var i = 0; i < window.Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                if (!window.Page_Validators[i].isvalid && typeof (window.Page_Validators[i].errormessage) == "string") {
                    counter= 1;
                    val+= '-  ' + window.Page_Validators[i].errormessage + '<br>';
                }
            }
            if (counter== 1) {
              //My validation pop up to display validations alert because this counter value remains 0 so this part is not executed.
            }
        }
 </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Now when I click on submit button then my server side code event is fired but my validation pop up doesn't appear.

I have even put this line in web.config:

```
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"></add>
```

But this is still not working as removing query string from response.redirect or from `windows.location.href` then my validation pop up successfully appears and it is working fine.

Comment: try returning false from the button client-side click when the page is not valid. Ensure you have no errors before that and during that code execution.

Comment: @rdmptn:but problem is my validation pop up are not firing because it is not going in my if condition

Comment: Does it even enter `checkvalidation()`? You have to be sure it enters RadCodeBlock

Comment: @Proleev:yeah it does enter and also it enter inside for loop but it doesnt goes inside if condiotion and so my counter variable value remains 0 so my validation message doesnt appears

Comment: Your 'if' condition - are both of those statements false or just one?

Comment: Then only logical thing to do is to log this:

`window.Page_Validators` 

and then check if it is even array and what type of error it contains.

Comment: @VictorySaber:You got a point but i havent check that but i guess it is the first condition where it might be getting false

Comment: @Proleev:i have removed server side onclick event and now my validation pop up appears

Comment: @VictorySaber:When i add onclick event to my button then i am getting flag value as 0 but when i remove onclick event then my flag value is 1

Comment: @VictorySaber:please see my updated question

Comment: @Proleev:please see my updated question

Comment: Is 'window.Page_Validators[i].isvalid' true or false? Is 'typeof (window.Page_Validators[i].errormessage) == "string")' true or false?

Comment: @VictorySaber:ok i am getting this 'window.Page_Validators[i].isvalid' as false and typeof (window.Page_Validators[i].errormessage) as true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as you say, `window.Page_Validators[i].isvalid` is `false` and `typeof (window.Page_Validators[i].errormessage)` is `true`, then we must go into the 'if' condition. The counter must be set to 1, and then must go into the 'if' later on.

I've changed the checks a little bit and have added the console logging to help you. In case anyone doesn't know, you can view these messages by hitting `F12` in the browser and clicking "Console".

```
function checkvalidation() {
        window.Page_ClientValidate('validate');
        var counter= 0;
        var val= '';
        for (var i = 0; i < window.Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            if ( (window.Page_Validators[i].isvalid === false) && typeof (window.Page_Validators[i].errormessage) == "string") {
                console.log("Inside the if condition");
                console.log(window.Page_Validators[i]);
                counter = 1;
                val+= '-  ' + window.Page_Validators[i].errormessage + '<br>';
            }
        }
        if (counter === 1) {
          //My validation pop up to display validations alert because this counter value remains 0 so this part is not executed.
        }
    }
```